# Firefox's userContent.css being overriden by CSS of the site

Tags: firefox

To override the styles for a particular site that I am developing/debugging for, I have set up an `userContent.css` stylesheet on Firefox. The stylesheet is sort of working, except that the precedence of the stylesheet seems wrong to me.

When I open the Inspector tool of Firefox, I see that styles from `userContent.css` are imported alright, but the styles are treated like browser's default styles. The styles get pushed way down in the precedence order. The styles from the CSS of the site appear way above my styles from `userContent.css` .

For example, `.container { ... }` from my `userContent.css` would be overridden by the same selector `.container { ... }` from the site, so the `.container { ... }` from my `userContent.css` is simply ignored.

If I want to override the styles of a site with `userContent.css`, then surely I would want its styles to be on top of everything originally from the site (in precedence order), right? Otherwise, why would I want to use `userContent.css` for?

Due to some development/debugging reasons, I would preferably not to set every rules in the `userContent.css` to be `!important` and neither do I want to change every selector (for example, from `.container` to `body .container`).

Simply put, I just want `userContent.css` to override the styles of a site.

Comment: You have to use `!important` or write a grease, violent, or tampermonkey script to load your styles at the end after everything else is loaded.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you for your reply. I have tried using Tampermonkey but it seems that Firefox won't allow access local file because of security reason, so I can't get Firefox to load the local CSS file.

Comment: You need to put your code in the script itself not try to load it from a local file.

Answer (score 0):

When several style sheets assign a value to a property of an element, then the conflict is resolved according to
[cascade rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade).

The order is :

1. user agent declarations (browser default style)
2. user normal declarations
3. author (page) normal declarations
4. author (page) important declarations
5. user important declarations

So author (page) `!important` declarations trump everything but user `!important` declarations.

`userContent.css` is loaded last, so has the highest priority.
If this wasn't enough, then the website has ignominiously used the
`!important` keyword in its rules, so nothing else but `!important`
in your rules will override it. Or perhaps your rules are not
specific enough, as the most specific rule always wins.

You could also use a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script to remove the `!important` from the CSS of the website, but this may require
some complexity.

Comment: Thank you, but as I said in the question, userContent.css seems to be loaded first and put to the lowest priority. Also Firefox won't allow access local file (even with Tampermonkey) because of security reason, so I can't get Firefox to load the local CSS file.